# How can this input lead to XSS?

Tags: post, xss

Here is the request Vega gave to my webpage:
`username=Joey-->">'>'" password=vega login=login`

What exactly is it trying to do with `Joey-->">'>'"`. Can someone explain how this POST request can determine XSS vulnerabilities?

Vega is a web vulnerability analysis tool. (https://subgraph.com/vega/)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about the tool itself, it appears to be trying to exit or "break out of" various tags and attributes:

- `-->` is used to end an HTML comment.  An attacker might try to exit a comment in order to execute Javascript on the page, as JavaScript inside an HTML comment will not execute
- `"` and `'` are used to delimit HTML attributes or JavaScript strings.  An attacker can try to do several things here:

  1. Exit an HTML attribute, allowing them to inject a potentially malicious HTML attribute.
  2. Exit a JavaScript String, allowing them to inject arbitrary JavaScript after the string is exited.
  3. Exit an HTML attribute, then attempt to exit the HTML tag using `>`.  Doing this might allow them to inject an arbitrary `<script>` tag and execute arbitrary JavaScript.
- `>` Is used to exit an HTML tag, after which an attacker might try to inject an arbitrary `<script>` tag with malicious JavaScript.

These are all **very** simple examples, just a basic idea of how an attacker might approach.